# How to count until a certain value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am just using formulas in excel and was wondering how you could count all the 0s until a 1 is reached, and then start the process over again. Would this be possible with just formulas?

Right now I am trying to use,

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(F2:F28,0)),1)
```

... but it does not seem to work.

Data:

```html
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(A2=0,A1=1),"",COUNTIF($A$1:A1,0)-SUM($B$1:B1))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: The $B$1:B1 is giving me the error that I have circular references

Comment: @AnnaLi  Remember the formula goes in **B2** not in **B1**

Answer (score 3):

**What you're describing here is known as a [`(Do) While`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_do_while_loop.htm) loop in VBA.**
Admittedly, something VBA is much better equipped to handle than a formula - literally needs few lines of code. Should be something you should consider looking into

> You can technically fake a `Do While` with a formula. But this is
>   generally a practice I would not exactly recommend.

Under presumption you data input starts in Cell F2 then formula in adjacent Column G2
`=IF(F2=0, SUM(G1, 1), 0)` and drag the formula accross. Produces the expected result

[image]

Comment: If you use `sum(G1, 1)` column header text will be ignored as a zero.

Comment: @Jeeped That's actually pretty smart. Thank you! Learned something new today :) *(or well, I knew sum ignores text values, but somehow it didn't hit me I could use it here as well)*

Comment: We pay for the overhead with every calculation due to wasted error checking cycles. Why not take advantage when we can?

Comment: How would I be able to do this in VBA? And I would like it done in the fashion that it would leave blank spaces until the 1, as in the answer I accepted.

Comment: Hi Anna, probably will be easier if you create a seperate question for that (and by that I also mean to do your research to see if the question is even necessary)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work according to your sample data,

```
=COUNTIF(F2:INDEX(F:F, IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:2)/(F$1:F2=1), 1), ROW(F2))), 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but it's not very elegant. Maybe someone else can improve on it. But here it is:

Assuming your data is in column A.

1) In `B1` enter a `1` if `A1` is a `0` or `0` if `A1` is a `1`.

2) In `B2` enter the formula `=IF(A2=0,B1+1,0)`

3) Drag the above formula all the way down

4) In `C1` enter the formula `=IF(B1>B2,B1,"")`

5) Drag the above formula all the way down

6) Column `C` should now have all of the counts of zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula in column `B`:

```
=IF(A3=1,COUNTIF(A$1:A2,0)-SUM(B$1:B1),"")
```

starting in row 2 and drag it down.

Answer (score -1):

Put 1 in the cell next to the first 0 (In my example that's in A1, so i've put 1 in B1);
Then try this =IF(A2=A1;B1+1;1)